# Theme structure for multi-site

Tags: 8, multi-sites

I have a multi-site setup with three themes. They look the same, but they are different in colors. What are best practices to setup my theme structure, in themes/custom/site1, site2, and site3, or in sites/site1/themes, sites/site2/themes, and sites/site3/themes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they only differ in color, you should provide a theme setting for choosing it and setup the theme in `/themes/custom/mymulticolortheme`, so it will become available for all sites. Otherwise you have to maintain multiple nearly identical themes, which is a time killer when you have to fix a bug or add a feature.

If you have different themes for each site you should place each theme in the particular site theme folder like `/sites/site1/themes/custom/myspecialthemeforsite1`, `/sites/site2/themes/custom/mytotalydifferentthemeforsite2` etc., so that they are only available for sites they belong to.

Comment: And for default site in `sites/default/themes/` ?

Comment: yes, if it is specific for the default site, otherwise use the web root folder `/themes/`.

Answer (score 0):

IN this case, where the themes differ only in color, you should create a single theme. And try using theme settings of color module to change the color as required.